# group by previous rows with conditions

Tags: sql

[image]

I have this data set.
I want to group by assigned by then by date, but I only want to see a count of the merchant that has a bigger than or equal to end date than the start date (taken only from previous dates), but I can't see a way to do it.

I want to see up to a certain date, what are the number of merchants assigned, that have not ended the assignment.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using (and Postgres and Redshift are **not** the same thing)

Comment: In addition to fixing the tags, please post sample data as text, not pictures, the code you've tried, the result set that you get, and a mock up of the result set that you want instead. Help us help you.